# Reading In From A File. Multiple Delimiters? C++

Tags: c++, file-io, delimiter

so I'm trying to read in some info from a file, but I've been having a really difficult time doing it. Here's the format of the file I'm trying to read in.

```
Name#Description
Name2#Description2 ...
NameX#DescriptionX
%
info1,info2,info3,info4 ...
infoX1,infoX2,infoX3,infoX4,
%
Keyword#Message
```

So what I'm trying to do is break up the first part of the code after every `#` and split the Name into one variable, and the Description into another variable. Then after the first `%` split each piece of info up into it's own variable. Finally, after the second `%` split those up by the `#` much like above, but different variables.

So I tried `while(getline(inFile, str, '%')` but it stops reading after the first line then goes to whatever is under the `%`. Having some trouble here, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you could split this up into several loops where the first loop parses the input up until the `%` character, get the position of this character in the file stream and start the next parsing loop from there and so on

Comment: My experience is pretty limited, how would I get the loop to stop at %?

Comment: @jus this is how you **Stop** a loop at %: `if (character == '%')` then `break;` or `continue;` where _break_ will literally go out of the loop and _continue_ will ignore all statements below it, increment the loop and proceed with "looping"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a (non-complete) structure for how you could go about this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(void) {

    const char* in_file_path = "foo.txt";
    std::ifstream in_file(in_file_path);

    std::string buffer = "";
    while (std::getline(in_file, buffer)) {
        //parse input using `#` as separator...
        if (buffer.at(0) == '%') {
            // get position of `%` char in stream using (e.g.) in_file.seekg
            break;
        }
    }
    // after getting position of first `%` char in stream, this loop 
    // will start from this position in the file
    while (std::getline(in_file, buffer)) {
        // parse input using `,` as separator...
        if (buffer.at(0) == `%`) {
            // get position of `%` char in stream using (e.g.) in_file.seekg
            break;
        }
    }

    // ... and so on for as many separations as you need until you hit end of file

}
```

This relies on using (for example), the `seekg` method of `std::ifstream`:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg